# Ошибка: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, c++, jni

Проблема такая, пытаюсь разобраться в JNI, но при запуске вылетает ошибка:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNItest.printHelloWorld()V
        at JNItest.printHelloWorld(Native Method)
        at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Код пишу в IntelliJ IDEA.

**Код JNItest.java:**

```
public class JNItest {
    static {
        System.load("F:/Android/Projects/three/bin/hello.dll");
        System.out.println("library loaded successfully");
    }

    native void printHelloWorld(); }
```

**Код main.java:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Работает на андроиде!");

        JNItest p = new JNItest();
        p.printHelloWorld();
    }
}
```

**JNItest.h:**

```
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class JNItest */

#ifndef _Included_JNItest
#define _Included_JNItest
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     JNItest
 * Method:    printHelloWorld
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNItest_printHelloWorld
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**JNITest.cpp:**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "JNITest.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNItest_printHelloWorld
(JNIEnv *, jobject) {
    std::cout << "Hello C";
}
```

Вроде бы все сделано верно. При запуске вижу:

```
     Работает на андроиде! 
         Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
         JNItest.printHelloWorld()V     
         at JNItest.printHelloWorld(Native Method)  
         at Main.main(Main.java:10)
         library loaded successfully
```

И что с этим делать? Вроде бы есть похожие вопросы, но способы решения ко мне не подошли. 
Спасибо!

Comment: где сам метод, в котором ошибка?

Comment: Надо полагать у вашей dll не находятся зависимости.

Comment: Метод в JNItest.java
Как найти зависимость?